# Возможно ли ускорить выполнение макроса?

Tags: excel, vba

Расскажу немного предыстории, надеюсь будет понятно.
Есть **файл-шаблон** (этот и все остальные файлы представлены таблицей Excel), где есть много записей(до 200к). Для задачи возьмем 10к. Его нужно загружать в программу, она считывает все данные и загружает их, если все ок. Если что-то неправильно, тогда в **файл - лог**, выгружает ошибки с номерами строк, под которыми они идут в файле шаблоне и описанием.

В общем, чтобы быстрее все загрузить, я ошибочные строки решил вырезать из **файла-шаблона** и вставить их в отдельный, допустим, **файл-ошибочные данные**.

Для решения вопроса я написал скрипт, которые открывает эти книги, считывает диапазоны, ищет по номеру строчки из лога строчку в файле-шаблоне и вырезает эту строчку... Очень долго вырезает(

```
For Each r In UniqLogR ''

   var1 = "A" & r 
   var2 = "CK" & r

   BaseR.Range(var1,var2).Cut
   'BaseR -  Диапазон данных в файле шаблоне'
   ErrorR(ClearRowsNum,1).Value = r
   ErrorR(ClearRowsNum,2).Activate
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   ClearRowsNum = ClearRowsNum + 1
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next R
```

Там конечно не все красиво, сильно не ругайтесь.
Эта часть выполняется дольше всего. Не особо понимаю почему, и тем более, как это ускорить.

В данный момент скинуть сами файлы нет возможности, они все заняты процессом.

Comment: Отключить обновление экрана, а после выполнения включить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забываем подключить библиотеку `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub CleanErrors()
    Dim WrongRecordsNums As New Dictionary, registred_wrongs As New Dictionary
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim row_nums_with_errors(), report(), valids_arr(), wrongs_arr(), header()
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long, key

    Const v_shift = 10
    Const report_rows_count = 200000
    Const report_columns_count = 90

    Dim t#, tt#

    t = Timer: tt = Timer

    WrongRecordsNums.CompareMode = TextCompare

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1лог.xlsx")

    row_nums_with_errors = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Value2

    wb.Close

    i = 1

    Do While Not IsEmpty(row_nums_with_errors(i, 1))
        WrongRecordsNums(CLng(row_nums_with_errors(i, 1)) - v_shift) = Empty
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ReDim wrongs_arr(WrongRecordsNums.Count, report_columns_count + 1)


    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Файл шаблон.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    header = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(v_shift, report_columns_count)).Value2
    report = Range(ws.Cells(v_shift + 1, 1), ws.Cells(report_rows_count + v_shift, report_columns_count)).Value2
    wb.Close: Set ws = Nothing

    Debug.Print "Переварили книги", Timer - t: t = Timer

    ReDim valids_arr(UBound(report, 1) - WrongRecordsNums.Count, report_columns_count)

    i = 0
    For Each key In WrongRecordsNums.Keys
        i = i + 1
        WrongRecordsNums(key) = report(key, 1)
        wrongs_arr(i, 1) = key + v_shift
        For j = 2 To UBound(wrongs_arr, 2)
            wrongs_arr(i, j) = report(key, j - 1)
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print "Создали массив неправильных", Timer - t: t = Timer

    For i = LBound(report, 1) To UBound(report, 1)
        If Not WrongRecordsNums.Exists(i) Then
            n = n + 1
            For j = LBound(report, 2) To UBound(report, 2)
                valids_arr(n, j) = report(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print "Создали массив правильных", Timer - t: t = Timer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(v_shift, report_columns_count))
    rng.Value2 = header

    Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(v_shift + 1, 1), ws.Cells(UBound(valids_arr, 1) + v_shift, report_columns_count))
    rng.Value2 = valids_arr

    Debug.Print "Выгрузили правильные", Timer - t: t = Timer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(UBound(wrongs_arr, 1), 91))
    rng.Value2 = wrongs_arr

    Debug.Print "Выгрузили неправильные", Timer - t
    Debug.Print "Время работы скрипта", Timer - tt
End Sub

# Время работы этапов выполнения в секундах:
# 
# Переварили книги             18,109375 
# Создали массив неправильных  0,21875 
# Создали массив правильных    1,3828125 
# Выгрузили правильные         16,5546875 
# Выгрузили неправильные       0,3984375 
# Время работы скрипта         36,671875
```

> Обрабатываемая таблица 200000 х 90, комп Core i5 8 gen, 8 GB RAM

Comment: Я думал насчет массивов, забыл добавить, в файле с данными -  не в двух столбцах данные. В одной строчке 90 столбцов, и они рандомно заполнены. В таком случае это тоже можно осуществить?

Comment: @bb.aleshka по сути получается так `all_records = Range("$A$1:$CL$1").Value2` Ну или задать диапазон через `Range(Такой-то_лист.Cells(1, 1), Такой-то_лист.Cells(1, 90))`

Comment: хм, получается, что 10 верхних строк и 90 столбцов заняты описанием, т.е. - шапкой.
Потом уже, с 11 строки и там сколько влезет, по 90 столбцов данных. По соображениям безопасности личных данных не могу кинуть сам файл, но потом сделаю пример  и добавлю к вопросу. 
В этих столбцах, с 1 по 90 - не во всех есть данные, поэтому я сначала вырезал всю строчку целиком, потом подумал, что быстрее будет вырезать только ту часть, что используется в таблице.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, просто пока не очень ясно представляю, как именно это будет. Сейчас еще кину картинку с кодом. Может там яснее будет. [PIC](https://ibb.co/SfvYh4t)

Comment: @bb.aleshka, Между 11-й и последней строкой могут быть строки не содержащие данные в столбцах с 1 по 90 (пустые строки)?

Comment: @bb.aleshka, кстати, что-бы избежать подобных зависаний, в каждый хоть сколько нибудь объемный цикл добавляйте процедуру `DoEvents`

Comment: Да, могут быть не содержащие данные в столбцах. Пустых строк нет, они заполняются одна за другой. Насчет DoEvents - не пробовал, буду делать

Comment: Полезная вещь по описанию! И все же, не понимаю. У меня этот шаблон тоже делается макросом. И в шаблон я копирую данные не 10к а по 50-80, и все хорошо, он работает где то минуты  3-5. То есть не так долго и соразмерно. А тут например ошибок будет 200 и он обрабатывает их целый час.(

Comment: @bb.aleshka, Сейчас попробую немного оптимизировать Ваш код с картинки, дополню ответ. И еще для уникализации значений лучше использовать словари, для этого нужно подключить в References библиотеку Scripting Runtimes или использовать вариант с созданим объэекта по типу `Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Comment: @ Andrey  *в каждый хоть сколько нибудь объемный цикл добавляйте процедуру DoEvents* - не очень хорошо. Оператор проверяет все прерывания. а это тоже время (хоть и небольшое)

Comment: @vikttur, на практике время срабатывания DoEvents это такая фигня по сравнению с зависшим хотя-бы минут на 20 excel

Comment: @vikttur, безусловно, если мы ловим милисекунды срабатывания при программировании (условно) UI тогда это имеет вес, если речь идет об операциях более емких по времени, эта процедура очень экономит нервы особенно при отладке, поскольку позволяет тормознуть зависший скрипт без киляния процесса приложения

Comment: При отладке - да, в рабочей программе - по минимуму. Нет, не советую совсем отказаться. А ускорить еще можно, наверное, если полнее видеть задачу и код

Comment: @vikttur не, ну я тоже не предлагаю использовать ее так `For i = 0 to 10: Debug.Print i: DoEvents: Wend` )))

Comment: Всю полностью задачу и код и файлы примеры скину чуть позже, когда этот макрос таки завершит свою работу. Не хочется все же, чтобы все что он наделал, просто так куда то делось..